# Is there a more succinct / pythonic way to do this? (counting longest seq of heads, tails in coin flips)

Tags: python

Count the longest sequence of heads and tails in 200 coin flips.
I did this - is there a niftier way to do it in python?  (without being too obfuscated)

```
import random

def toss(n):
    count = [0,0]
    longest = [0,0]
    for i in xrange(n):
        coinface = random.randrange(2)
        count[coinface] += 1
        count[not coinface] = 0

        if count[coinface] > longest[coinface]:
            longest[coinface] = count[coinface]      
        #print coinface, count, longest  

    print "longest sequence heads %d, tails %d" %tuple(longest)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    toss(200)
```

see [this](http://www.rexswain.com/benford.html) for what prompted my playing

Comment: Someone could do this fabled "math" thing and just give you a formula.

Comment: I'm amazed at how many different solutions cropped up despite 'There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.' Thanks all, I need to get an openid so I can vote etc next time. 

Cheers 

Steve

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
def coins(num):
    lst = [random.randrange(2) for i in range(num)]
    lst = [(i, len(list(j))) for i, j in itertools.groupby(lst)]
    tails = max(j for i, j in lst if i)
    heads = max(j for i, j in lst if not i)
    return {1: tails, 0: heads}
```

Comment: Thank God someone else used `itertools` instead of voting up the string-splitting and joining horror that currently leads.

Comment: For really large values of num, might be better to use a generator instead of actually creating the whole list.

Comment: @Emil: while I appreciate your suggestion, I'd point out that 1) it's a list of `1`s and `0`s; 2) an intermediate lists are going to take far more memory

Comment: Mine doesnt use a list na na. Anyway I'm going for this one as it's the kind of thing I was looking for. I'm amazed at how many different solutions cropped up despite 'There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.'

Thanks all, I need to get an openid so I can vote etc next time.

Cheers
Steve

Comment: +1: Very legible!  I also like Alex's response, which is very memory efficient, but which requires more effort to understand.

Answer (score 11):

```
import collections, itertools, random

def makesequence(choices=2, length=200):
  return [random.randrange(choices) for _ in itertools.repeat(None, length)]

def runlengths(sequence):
  runlength_by_item = collections.defaultdict(set)
  for key, group in itertools.groupby(sequence):
    runlength_by_item[key].add(sum(1 for _ in group))
  return dict((k, max(v)) for k, v in runlength_by_item.items())
```

As you'll notice, this is much more "decoupled" -- `runlengths` is a completely general way to determine the maximal run-lengths of different hashable items in any iterable (highly reusable if you need such run-lengths in a variety of different contexts), just as `makesequence` is a completely general way to make a list of random numbers given list length and number of choices for each random number.  Putting these two together may not offer an optimal point-solution to a given, highly specific problem, but it will come close, and building up your little library of reusable "building blocks" will have much higher longer-term returns than just solving each specific problem by entirely dedicated code.

Comment: It was actually your answers to questions that involve `itertools` that introduced me to the concept.  I'm glad you bang that drum repeatedly.

Comment: Can you use len(group) isntead of sum(1 for _ in group)?

Comment: I'm learning stuff today, especially how much I don't know! Thanks for this

Comment: @Emil: `group` is a `itertools._grouper` object, that doesn't have `len`, alternative would be to convert it to `list` first.

Comment: Dude, this is so YAGNI - way too general, and made understanding this more difficult than it should have.

Comment: I agree about the YAGNI, nonetheless I'm upvoting this for the breathtaking use of `itertools.repeat`.  Though if you're going to go that far, why not return a generator instead of a list?

Comment: @Robert Rossney - breathtaking use? What about useless? a range(length) would have had the same effect, without people having to lookup whether repeat() actually does something more.

Comment: It's a generator-based approach to iterating over a range.  That's good to know about.  Even better in this case, though, would be `itertools.imap(random.randrange, itertools.repeat(choices, length))`.

Comment: @abyx, learning itertools and using it wisely is one of the key secrets to great scalability in Python: unless you're sure you're writing code that nobody will ever particularly care for, making it scalable's a good precaution -- and not at all complicated; those "people" who previously ignored itertools and are "forced" to look it up actually are the great winners here, because they're getting exposed to an awesome, very practical tool; see @Jed's comment.  @Robert, yes, pushing "streamingness" up one notch to use imap is quite possible here, too.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `itertools`, which is a much more Pythonic way to do this:

```
def toss(n):
    rolls = [random.randrange(2) for i in xrange(n)]
    maximums = [0, 0]
    for which, grp in itertools.groupby(rolls):
        maximums[which] = max(len(list(grp)), maximums[which])

    print "Longest sequence of heads %d, tails %d" % tuple(maximums)
```

Comment: Thanks Jed, this is looking better, I need to look into itertools a bit more to follow this. Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Another inefficient solution :-)

```
import random, re
s = ''.join(str(random.randrange(2)) for c in range(10))
print s
print max(re.findall(r'0+', s))
print max(re.findall(r'1+', s))

>>> 
0011100100
00
111
>>>
```

Comment: If you're only looking for one set of runs, that's not inefficient at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> def toss(count):
        result = []
        for i in range(count):
            result.append("HT"[random.randrange(0, 2)])
        return ''.join(result)

>>> s = toss(200)
>>> h_max = max(len(x) for x in s.split("T"))
>>> t_max = max(len(x) for x in s.split("H"))
>>> print h_max, t_max
4 6
```

Comment: Seriously, why is this getting voted up? I wish I could vote it down twice.

Comment: "Simple is better than complex."

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really pythonic so much as tortured, but here's a short version (with meaningless 1-character variable names, no less!)

```
import random
x = ''.join([chr(random.randrange(2)) for i in range(200)])
print max([len(s) for s in x.split(chr(0)) + x.split(chr(1))])
```

Comment: ok, I think that's giving me the max of _either_ heads or tails' seq count right? thanks.

Comment: Yep. Sorry. Slightly misread the question, but easily corrected.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably an axiom that any code can be made more succinct.  Yours looks perfectly pythonic, though.

Actually, on reflection perhaps there is no succinctness axiom like that.  If [succinct](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/succinct) means "marked by compact precise expression without wasted words," and if by "words" we mean words of code and not of memory, then a single word program cannot be made more succinct (unless, perhaps, it is the "exit" program).

If [pythonic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pythonic) means "of extraordinary size and power", then it seems antagonistic to succinctness unless we restrict our definition to power only.   I'm not convinced your program resembles a prophetic oracle at all, although you might implement it as an ascii portrait of a particular prophetic oracle.   It doesn't look like a snake, so there's room for improvement there too.

```
import random

def toss(n):
    '''
     ___     ____________
<<<((__O\   (__<>___<>__ \   ____
       \ \_(__<>___<>__)\O\_/O___>-<  hiss
        \O__<>___<>___<>)\___/

    '''
    count = [0,0]
    longest = [0,0]
    for i in xrange(n):
        coinface = random.randrange(2)
        count[coinface] += 1
        count[not coinface] = 0

        if count[coinface] > longest[coinface]:
            longest[coinface] = count[coinface]
        #print coinface, count, longest

    print "longest sequence heads %d, tails %d" %tuple(longest)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    toss(200)
```

Nifty, huh?

Comment: pythonic means: http://docs.python.org/glossary#term-pythonic
as well as `import this`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random, itertools

def toss(n):
    faces = (random.randrange(2) for i in range(n))
    longest = [0, 0]
    for face, seq in itertools.groupby(faces):
        longest[face] = max(longest[face], len(list(seq)))
    print "longest sequence heads %d, tails %d" % tuple(longest)
```

Comment: looks about the same as Jed's above which I also like, thanks

Comment: @Steve: There is a difference. I've kept the function memory efficient as original (in question) was, so it can be used for very large `n`, while Jed's and SilentGhost's solutions create large intermediate arrays.

Answer (score 1):

### String scanning algorithm

If you are looking for a fast algorithm, then you can use the algorithm I developed recently for an interview question that asked for the longest string of consecutive letters in a string. [See blog entry here](http://www.iwebthereforeiam.com/iwebthereforeiam/2009/11/interview-question-part-ii-longest-sequence-in-string.html).

```
def search_longest_substring(s):
    """
    >>> search_longest_substring('AABBBBCBBBBACCDDDDDDAAABBBBCBBBBACCDDDDDDDAAABBBBCBBBBACCDDDDDDA')
    (7, 'D')
    """
    def find_left(s, midc, mid, left):
        for j in range(mid-1, left-1, -1):
            if s[j] != midc:
                return j + 1
        return left
    def find_right(s, midc, mid, right):
        for k in range(mid+1, right):
            if s[k] != midc:
                return k
        return right
    i, longest = 0, (0, '')
    while i < len(s):
        c = s[i]
        j = find_left(s, c, i, i-longest[0])
        k = find_right(s, c, i, len(s))
        if k-j > longest[0]:
            longest = (k-j, c)
        i = k + longest[0]
    return longest

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import random
    heads_or_tails = "".join(["HT"[random.randrange(0, 2)] for _ in range(20)])
    print search_longest_substring(heads_or_tails)
    print heads_or_tails
```

This algorithm is O(n) in worst case (all coin flips are identical) or O(n/m) in average case (where m is the length of the longest match). Feel free to correct me on this.

The code is not especially pythonic (i.e. it does not use list comprehensions or `itertools` or other stuff). It's in python and it's a good algorithm.

### Micro-optimizations

For the micro-optimization crowd, here are changes that make this really scream in python 2.6 on a Windows Vista laptop:

```
def find_left(s, midc, mid, left):
    j = mid - 1
    while j >= 0:
        if s[j] != midc:
            return j + 1
        j -=  1
    return left
def find_right(s, midc, mid, right):
    k = mid+1
    while k < right:
        if s[k] != midc:
            return k
        k += 1
    return right
```

Timing results for 1000 iterations with `timeit`:

```
range: 2.670
xrange: 0.3268
while-loop: 0.255
```

Adding `psyco` import to the file:

```
try:
    import psyco
    psyco.full()
except ImportError:
    pass
```

0.011 on 1000 iterations with `psyco` and while-loop. So with judicious micros-optimizations and importing `psyco`, the code runs 250-ish times faster.

Comment: BTW, you might want to change those two range calls to xrange calls (Python 2, of course).  As the length of the trial sequences increases, all those extra list creations start to add up.  With a length of 2000, xrange version ran ~10 times faster than range version (Python 2.6).

Comment: @Ned: Thanks. If I were going to do that, I'd explore using a while loop. Maybe I'll look into that after my first up-vote.

Comment: The code you posted here is different than the one on your blog post. For one thing, it doesn't give the right answer for the test set you used in your post. This returns (6, 'D') and the blog code returns (7, 'D'), which is correct.

Comment: @dalke: fixed that. Added doctest.